# change menu by clicking - Bootstrap

Tags: menu, click, responsive, hamburger-menu

I want to have a Dashboard menu. If i click the burger icon, the menu have to change like on the pictures.

From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Here is my code:
**HTML**

```
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!-- Line 1-->
                <li class="listyle" >
                  <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#toggleDemo" data-parent="#sidenav01" class="collapsed">
                <span style="color:#e20074">  <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span>&nbsp; 1. Item</span>
                  </a>
                  <div class="collapse" id="toggleDemo" style="height: 0px;">
                    <ul class="nav nav-list">
                      <li><a href="#">Submenu1.1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Submenu1.2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Submenu1.3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below URL, I have added some css and Js.

```
.navbar-nav {
        width:200px;
        transition:all 0.8s ease;
    }
    .glyphicon{
        transition:all 0.9s ease;
    }
    .navbar-nav li{
        width:200px;
    }
    .someClass {
        width:50px;
        overflow:hidden;
        display:block;

    }
    .someClass .glyphicon{
        color:#0f0d9f;
        font-size:30px;
    }



$('.glyphicon-menu-hamburger').click( function() {
    $(".navbar-nav").toggleClass("someClass");
} );
```

[ref url](http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/963/)

Comment: I've been too early pleased. In the fiddle this is working fine. On my own files are happen nothing. What could i do?

Comment: Please include Jquery library file in html.
Download the jQuery library from jQuery.com OR include jQuery from a CDN.

Comment: The library are included but is still not working: Here the <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: Here its working fine.... Please check below html format, Jquery file should be in header

<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Your html
<script>
$('.glyphicon-menu-hamburger').click( function() {
    $(".navbar-nav").toggleClass("someClass");
} );
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Now it works! My script was outside html, this was the mistake. Thanks a ton! Do you also know how can i combine this with columns in boostrap? If i click the icon to change from col-2 to col-1 ?

Comment: Please change Js like:
$('.glyphicon-menu-hamburger').click( function() {
    $(".navbar-nav").toggleClass('col-1').toggleClass('col-2')
} );

Ref :http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/967/